# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 464 and input n_features is 2

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, transform, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

I am tryin to predict the cost of perfumes but I got error in the line "answer = (clf.predict(result))"

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM info')
    info = cursor.fetchall()
    for line in info:
        z.append(line[0:2])
        y.append(line[2])

    enc.fit(z)
    x = enc.transform(z).toarray()

    result = []
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(x, y)
    new = input('enter the Model, Volume of your perfume to see the cost: example = Midnighto,50 ').split(',')
    enc.fit([new])
    result = enc.transform([new]).toarray()

    answer = (clf.predict(result))
    print(answer)
```

Comment: Please include details about the error and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to fit `enc` again with your new input, only transform with the function fitted with X (what you do is OneHotEncoding the new sample taking in consideration only one possible value of the feature, **you have to consider all the possible categories of the feature you have in your X data**). So delete the next row:

```
enc.fit([new])
```

After that, please check if X and results has the same number of features. You can use function `shape`.

Furthermore, I recommend you use training and test data to see if your model is overfitted or not. Then, you can apply your personal predict.

Comment: Happy it was useful for you!